# Yocto meta-oe recipe parsing error

Tags: yocto, openembedded, banana-pi

I am working on building yocto for banana pro board and using Jethro 2.0     version.I modified meta-sunxi bsp according to banana pro.But when I add meta-oe layer to project,I get following error

> ParseError at ~/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-connectivity/networkmanager/networkmanager_1.0.10.bb:12: Could not inherit file classes/bash-completion.bbclass

What is my mistake?Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using meta-oe from git master, but oe-core Jethro.  Checkout the jethro branch of meta-oe.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It working but I got following error in compile time:  "user requested feature sdl configure was not able to find it. install sdl devel"

Comment: You need to do what it says: install the SDL development packages on your distro, or disable SDL in qemu (see your local.conf).

Comment: How can i install them? I added all recipe about sdl but I got same error.

Comment: Is the sdl-dev package for your host, ie outside of the bitbake environment. Just run apt-get out whatever your distro uses.

Comment: better you can comment the sdl line in build/conf/local.conf